# How can I keep a hanging cloth hydrated?

Tags: moisture, cooling, temperature, evaporative-cooling

As the summers are approaching, it kinda gets hot in my room. I make it cooler by dipping a bed-sheet in water and then hanging it on the curtain rod next to the window.

This cools down the air that enters my room and it feels awesome to be in this naturally-cooled room.

However, the cloth dries up every hour. When this happens I need to drench it in water, wring it, so that it's not soaking wet, and then hang it up again.

**Qs: I'm wondering if there's a way I could keep this cloth hydrated throughout the day? Is there something that I could place on top of the curtain rod, that releases water slowly to keep the cloth hydrated?**

Comment: A furnace humidifier would do pretty much what you are after but  would definitely take some retrofitting tinkering to make it work and be safe.

Comment: They're about $1k. I'm installing one in my parents' home now.

Comment: @EricF I find this system to be more "fun" somehow. There's a kind of a "Honey, I fixed it" appeal as well as the "caveman living" appeal.

Comment: @Mugen It could be a fun learning experience definitely! Of course an A/C window unit ($50-$200) is way cheaper but there is no fun in that

Comment: might pick up an IV with an adjustable drip if you want to top-feed it.

Comment: @dandavis What's that? What's the name of the product that I'm searching for?

Answer (score 3):

Place the bottom of the fabric in a shallow pan of water. It'll wick moisture continuously until the pan is empty. It should last a day at least, though.

You could even suspend a wallpaper tray from the fabric itself, which you'd install on the curtain rod (assuming that it's robust enough).

[image]

Place a rod through the ends of the tray with the curtain's hem slipped over the rod. It should be stable enough if you only fill it say 1/3 full and keep the rod up high.

Or install a curtain rod at the tray location and hang the try on that.

```
        _________________________________
       |  ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧  |
=======|=================================|====== <-- curtain rod
       |                                 |           through double hem
       |  ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧  |
       |                                 |
       |                                 |
       |  ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧  |
       |                                 |
     . |.................................| .
   =========================================== <-- curtain rod
     | |  ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧ ♧  | |       through holes in 
     |_____________________________________|       ends of tray 
                                                   or straight rod
                                                   through tray ends 
                                                   and curtain hem
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm somehow not able to vizualize pt#2 and #3. When you say hang the hem over the rod, I'm not able to picture it. Isn't hem the stiched linings on the curtain? Those lines are vertical and I'm not sure how we could slip the hem over the rod. As for pt# 3, the curtain rod is already installed. I think you mean install the tray at the curtain rod location? It would be great if you could add a rough sketch or something, I would personally like to keep something at the top of the curtain rod so that it doesn't disturb the visible space.

Comment: Curtains are usually double-hemmed at the top, with the lower hem creating the channel through which the curtain rod is run. I'll sketch it up.

Comment: That's one hell of a diagram! I can now see that we're running the curtain rod literally through the wallpaper tray. This also means that the rod cannot run through anywhere near the bottom of the tray or else the water might leak out pretty fast. So the rod has to go through the top of the tray. The curtain is attached to the rod (and assuming that the tray is somehow fixed at an angle), the top part of the curtain kinda flows over the tray before falling. That top part (double hem) might dip into the water inside the tray (hems are usually outward facing but this would require an inward..(1)

Comment: (1).. facing hem. As long as the inward-hem, at the top part of the curtain dips into the water it'll wick the water and the solution will work. However, if the hem doesn't dip in deep enough then the wick will work only for a short duration and then there wouldn't be any contact with the water.

Comment: I'm wondering whether there is an easier mechanism to put at the top part of the curtains. Perhaps some kind of sponge that's soaked up a lot of water but doesn't release it too quickly. Or some other mechanism.